# Error with UIAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uialertcontroller

I am trying to have an alert pop up once a button is pressed. I want the art to be titled "Would you like to mine for materials" and give two option; yes and no. If yes is chosen then i want this to be implemented

```
Ironcnt.setvalue(forkey: "Iron")-3
```

and if no is chosen then the alert view will disappear. Here is the code that i wrote. When i tested this out in the simulator it crashed. I have also attached a screenshot of what the debugger said.

```
import UIKit

let Ironcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let Goldcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let Fiveth = UserDefaults.standard

let shipcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let empirecnt = UserDefaults.standard

var fiveth = Int()
var iron = Int()
var gold = Int()
var ships = Int()
var empires = Int()

class one: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fiveth1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var iron1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gold1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ships1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var empire1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var planet: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var webViewBG: UIWebView!

@IBAction func emp(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"title", message:"this is an alert", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert); alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"action1",style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)); self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

@IBAction func mat(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Would you like to mine for materials?", message:"This will cost you two Fiveth", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)); self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default , handler: nil));
        self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WebViewContent", ofType: "html")
    let htmlURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
    let html = try? Data(contentsOf: htmlURL)

    self.webViewBG.load(html!, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: htmlURL.deletingLastPathComponent())

    if (Fiveth.value(forKey: "Fiveth") != nil){
        fiveth = Fiveth.value(forKey: "Fiveth") as! NSInteger!
        fiveth1.text = NSString(format: "Fiveth: %i", fiveth) as String
    }
    if (Ironcnt.value(forKey: "Ironcnt") != nil){
        iron = Ironcnt.value(forKey: "Ironcnt") as! NSInteger!
        iron1.text = NSString(format: "Iron: %i", iron) as String
    }
    if (Goldcnt.value(forKey: "Goldcnt") != nil){
        gold = Goldcnt.value(forKey: "Goldcnt") as! NSInteger!
        gold1.text = NSString(format: "Gold: %i", gold) as String
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**:

You call two times `present(_:animated:completion:)` to present the alert controller after adding each of the actions.

**Solution**:

Just call it one time after adding the actions and add your code which should be executed after choosing the yes action in the handler of it.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Would you like to mine for materials?", message: "This will cost you two Fiveth", preferredStyle: .alert)
let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil)
let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in
  // here you can add your code which should be executed after choosing the yes action
  Ironcnt.setvalue(forkey: "Iron")-3
}

alert.addAction(noAction)
alert.addAction(yesAction)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to present the alert twice.
Remove the first `self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)` after setting the first action.